# Python remove from inventory issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

To summarize it all up, I’m making a text adventure game, I’m newish to python and done lots of research to make a working inventory. I figured out how to add to the inventory and print said items, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove a item. Please help.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armor, weight, price):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armor = armor
        self.weight = weight
        self.price = price

class Inventory(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items[item.name] = item

    def print_items(self):
        print('\t'.join(['Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Lb', 'Val']))
        for item in self.items.values():
            print('\t'.join([str(x) for 

x in [item.name, item.attack, item.armor, item.weight, item.price]]))

inventory = Inventory()
```

Here’s the code, someone help a man out, I’m using python 3.8

Comment: Try `self.items.pop(item.name)`

Comment: Removing an item from a list is documented in any tutorial on lists.

Comment: `x in [item.name, item.attack, item.armor, item.weight, item.price]]))` <- what are those `))` doing at the end of the line?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: No I haven’t, I should’ve, it would be good to know that I’m being taught by a school coding class and might not have gotten to that yet, and the parentheses are apart of the above code that got split apart without me knowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will remove the `item` from the `self.items` dictionary.

```py
def remove_item(self, item):
        del self.items[item.name]
```

Comment: I’ve tried that but I keep getting this error ``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iCloud/Testinf code.py", line 21
    def remove_item(self, item):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: It should work. Sometimes python points out odd lines, so check around it for syntax errors. Also for future reference, things you've already tried should be a part of your original question so that you don't get answers in this respect

Comment: Ah ok sorry, it’s just im not seeing exactly what the syntax error is, it’s at the very beginning of the “def” command, as if the entire function is incorrect

Comment: Figured out the issue, some code was jumbled, thank you this actually works, I guess I just didn’t catch that code was split apart

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_item(self, item_name):
        self.items={k:v for k,v in self.items.items() if not k==item_name}

def delete_item(self, item_name):
    self.items=self.items.pop(item_name)
```